# How to Sink output to the json file in Hazelcast Jet?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am new to Hazelcast Jet and in my application I am using jdbc source, this source returning List of Map which I have to Sink in one of json file but when I use Sinks.json it create json directory how can I sink it to particular json file?
For E.g.

```
           BatchSource<List<Map<String, Object>> jdbcSource = Sources
            .jdbc(() -> conn,
                (con, parallelism, index) -> {
                   // query execution
           }, r ->  {
                 return this.mapResultSet1(r);
           });
          jdbcSource.writeTo(Sinks.json("/opt/test.json"));
```

Please let me know how can I sink my result to json file?

Answer (score 2):

Consider aggregating the records to a list before sinking to the JSON file.

```
jdbcSource
    .aggregate(AggregateOperations.toList())
    .writeTo(Sinks.json("directory-where-a-single-file-will-be-created"))
```

Comment: Yes my data is coming from  aggregate operations, How can we name that file as there can be multiple files? and it not working giving this error                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Value

Comment: This link helped me out to create a json sink: https://jet-start.sh/docs/how-tos/custom-sink